# How to pass array(or pointer) in such a way that we can manipulate but the change should not reflect inside main function?

Tags: arrays, c, function

I want any `int` array inside `main()` function in such a way that I can not manipulate it inside the `main()` function but I can pass it to the other function to make some changes and again I don't want the reflection of that change in the array of `main` function? Is there some way apart from copying? Please suggest me.
Here is a sample program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun( int *arr);
int main()
{
    const int a[]={1,2,10,20};
     
     //a[3]=42;        I can not do as the array is read only
     
    fun(a);
    printf("%d ",a[3]);  //the change is reflected here and all I want is not to reflect any change here
    
    return 0;
}

void fun(int *arr)
{
    *(arr+3)=42;    //doing this I want change only inside this function
}
```

The output is **42**. All I want is the output **20** i.e ```a[3]``` of ```main()```function

Comment: You can pass an array as a field in a `struct` passed by value. For example `struct a { int as[4]; }; void fun(struct a) { ... }`

Comment: Uncommenting  `//arr[3]=42;` is invalid as `arr[]` does not exist.  Perhaps edit to `a[3]`.

Answer (score 1):

No. C is a low-level language, so what you see is what you get. Meaning if you are manipulating a data area (ie changing memory contents) the only way to not affect an "original" is to be manipulating *a copy.*

Comment: @Yunnosch Not really true - OP stated "... I can pass it to the other function ...".  Passing a copy of any kind is not really passing *pass[ing] it*.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way apart from copying?

Not really.  Code could reduce copying by restoring select array elements.

```
void fun(int *arr) {
  int orignal_3 = *(arr+3);

  *(arr+3)=42;    //doing this I want change only inside this function
  // ...

  *(arr+3) = orignal_3;
}
```

---

Note that OP's current code has *undefined* behavior due to `const` in `const int a[]={1,2,10,20};` and `fun()` `*(arr+3)=42;`.  Best to compile with all warnings enabled.

```
error: passing argument 1 of 'fun' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want any `int` array inside `main()` function in such a way that I can not manipulate it inside the `main()` function but I can pass it to the other function to make some changes and again I don't want the reflection of that change in the array of `main` function?

Consider it at a higher level. You want to modify an object.  No matter where you do this, all observers of that object will be able to see the changes.  Therefore, if `main`'s object must not be modified then *no* function may modify it.  If another function wants a similar object that it can modify, then that object must be a copy.

> Is there some way apart from copying?

No.

Perhaps the question is inspired by C's pass-by-value semantics, which have the result that functions *automatically* receive copies of the arguments presented by the caller.  The fine point surrounding arrays in this area is that you cannot pass an array as a function argument *at all*.  That concept cannot be expressed in C, because array-valued expressions are automatically converted to pointers in almost all contexts where they appear, including function calls' argument lists.  The function receives a copy *of the pointer* in such cases, and that points to the storage that the original array occupies.